# Rancid/VieWVC - cvs - keep only latest revisios/ remove older versions

Tags: version-control, version, cvs, revision-history, jus

I'm using Rancid with ViewVC as "front end" for reviewing config files of network devices

I would want to keep only latest revision number for all devices, and to remove old ones

```
cvs -d /usr/local/rancid/var/CVS rlog Switches
```

Output example:

```
RCS file: /usr/local/rancid/var/CVS/Switches/configs/Attic/1.1.1.1,v
head: 1.3
branch:
locks: strict
access list:
symbolic names:
keyword substitution: o
total revisions: 3;     selected revisions: 3
description:
----------------------------
revision 1.3
date: 2020/01/17 11:39:40;  author: rancid;  state: dead;  lines: +0 -0
deleted router 1.1.1.1
----------------------------
revision 1.2
date: 2020/01/17 11:00:14;  author: rancid;  state: Exp;  lines: +2 -0
updates
----------------------------
revision 1.1
date: 2020/01/17 08:23:44;  author: rancid;  state: Exp;
new router
=============================================================================

RCS file: /usr/local/rancid/var/CVS/Switches/configs/1.1.1.2,v
head: 1.2
branch:
locks: strict
access list:
symbolic names:
keyword substitution: o
total revisions: 2;     selected revisions: 2
description:
----------------------------
revision 1.2
date: 2020/01/20 07:29:34;  author: rancid;  state: Exp;  lines: +578 -0
updates
----------------------------
revision 1.1
date: 2020/01/17 11:57:40;  author: rancid;  state: Exp;
new router
=============================================================================

RCS file: /usr/local/rancid/var/CVS/Switches/configs/1.1.1.3,v
head: 1.2
branch:
locks: strict
access list:
symbolic names:
keyword substitution: o
total revisions: 2;     selected revisions: 2
description:
----------------------------
revision 1.2
date: 2020/01/17 11:39:57;  author: rancid;  state: Exp;  lines: +535 -0
updates
----------------------------
revision 1.1
date: 2020/01/17 11:39:39;  author: rancid;  state: Exp;
new router
=============================================================================

RCS file: /usr/local/rancid/var/CVS/Switches/configs/1.1.1.4,v
head: 1.10
branch:
locks: strict
access list:
symbolic names:
keyword substitution: o
total revisions: 10;    selected revisions: 10
description:
----------------------------
revision 1.10
date: 2020/01/16 13:42:54;  author: rancid;  state: Exp;  lines: +245 -0
updates
----------------------------
revision 1.9
date: 2020/01/16 13:42:44;  author: rancid;  state: Exp;  lines: +0 -245
new router
----------------------------
revision 1.8
date: 2020/01/16 13:41:20;  author: rancid;  state: dead;  lines: +0 -0
deleted router 1.1.1.4
----------------------------
revision 1.7
date: 2020/01/16 13:37:12;  author: rancid;  state: Exp;  lines: +245 -0
updates
----------------------------
revision 1.6
date: 2020/01/16 13:37:05;  author: rancid;  state: Exp;  lines: +0 -245
new router
----------------------------
revision 1.5
date: 2020/01/16 13:29:54;  author: rancid;  state: dead;  lines: +0 -0
deleted router 1.1.1.4
----------------------------
revision 1.4
date: 2020/01/16 11:33:03;  author: rancid;  state: Exp;  lines: +245 -0
updates
----------------------------
revision 1.3
date: 2020/01/16 11:23:45;  author: rancid;  state: Exp;  lines: +0 -0
new router
----------------------------
revision 1.2
date: 2020/01/16 11:16:27;  author: rancid;  state: dead;  lines: +0 -0
deleted router 1.1.1.4
----------------------------
revision 1.1
date: 2020/01/16 11:00:01;  author: rancid;  state: Exp;
new router
```

Just for a test,from `/usr/local/rancid` i tried

```
cvs -d /usr/local/rancid/var/CVS admin -o :"1.1" Switches
```

But getting

`cvs admin: /usr/local/rancid/var/CVS/Switches/configs/1.1.1.2,v: Revision rev 1.1 doesn't exist`

Tried with specific file:

```
cvs -d /usr/local/rancid/var/CVS admin -o :"1.1" Routers/configs/1.1.1.1,v

 cvs -d /usr/local/rancid/var/CVS admin -o :"1.1" /usr/local/rancid/var/CVS/Routers/configs/1.1.1.1,v
```

But getting

```
cvs admin: cannot open CVS/Entries for reading: No such file or directory
cvs admin: nothing known about 1.1.1.1,v
```

Answer (score 0):

ok, figured it out, just had to exit `/usr/local/rancid/var/'  path,for example /tmp

and type `cvs -d /usr/local/rancid/var/CVS checkout Switches`

then execute

```
cvs -d /usr/local/rancid/var/CVS admin -o :1.1 Switches/config/1.1.1.1
```

and all revisions with 1.1 are deleted